# Pass outlook Item to function mentioned in onAction attribute of Ribbon xml in C#

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin

I have created a simple VSTO outlook add-in whose purpose is to automatically set the subject of mail when reply button is clicked. I've added an EventHandler, `Outlook.ItemEvents_10_ReplyEventHandler` on MailItem. So whenever reply button is clicked, a callback function is triggered, let's say `func()` from `ThisAddIn.cs class`. This much works fine.

Then, I generated a button in context menu using Ribbon. Currently, when I click on that button, it displays a `MessageBox` indicating that `onAction` for this control is working and the function for displaying the `MessageBox` is written in `MyRibbon.cs class`.
My Ribbon.xml file :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui" onLoad="Ribbon_Load">
  <ribbon>
  </ribbon>
  <contextMenus>
      <contextMenus> 
        <contextMenu idMso="ContextMenuMailItem"> 
         <button id="AddSubject" label="Add a Subject" onAction= "AddSubject" /> 
        </contextMenu> 
  <contextMenus>    
</customUI>
```

`AddSubject` function definition in `MyRibbon.cs` class

```cs
        public void AddSubject(Office.IRibbonControl control)
        {
            if(control.Context is Outlook.Selection)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Selection");
                Outlook.MailItem mi = control.Context as Outlook.MailItem; //mi is null
                Console.WriteLine("Go the mail");
                Globals.ThisAddIn.CreateSubjectLine(mi);

            }          
        }
```

Function from where Ribbon object is being created in ThisAddIn.cs class :

```cs
        protected override Microsoft.Office.Core.IRibbonExtensibility CreateRibbonExtensibilityObject()
        {
            return new Ribbon1();
        }
```

Now, I'm not getting how can I call `func()` of `ThisAddIn.cs class` and pass `object` in it(in this case MailItem) from `AddSubject` callback function defined in `MyRibbon.cs` class?
I've tried to refer this (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2010/ee692172(v=office.14)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) document but I can't the project mentioned in it.

I'm not even sure if I have written ribbon.xml file correctly and if it is aligned with what I wish to achieve. Any proof of concept or reference will be of great help too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`IRibbonControl` object will be passed as a parameter to your event handler. Cast `IRibbonControl.Context` as either `Inspector` (use `Inspector.CurrentItem` then) or as `Explorer` (use `Explorer.Selection` collection or `Explorer.InlineResponse`)

Comment: I'm getting ```System.NullReferenceException:Object reference not set to an instance of an object.``` for ```inspector``` in this statement ```Outlook.Inspector inspector = control.Context as Outlook.Inspector;```. inspector is being set to null. Can you suggest something here?

Comment: Is your ribbon control in the Inspector or Explorer?

Comment: I'm kind of newbie in c# and not sure what is Ribbon control? Googling it just gives result of how Ribbons can be customised. Do you mean callback function AddSubject ?

Comment: That looks fine to me. But for an Explorer context menu button, Control.Context will be `Selection` object.

Comment: Yeah.  ```if(control.Context is Outlook.Selection)```  returns ```true```. Thanks for the help.